# Does passing parameters by reference in C++ have to be manual?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I am learning C++ and was reading a [book on it](http://isocpp.org/images/uploads/2-Tour-Basics.pdf) where I came across this:

```
struct Vector{
   int size;
   double* elem;
}

void vector_init(Vector& v, int s){
   v.size = s;
   v.elem = new double[s];
}
```

So here, would `void vector_init(Vector v, int s)`, without the reference operator, be wrong? Do I have to manually pass by reference using `&` while passing objects, structs, arrays or anything else as parameters? Also are there any alternate ways to do this? like say `void vector_init(Vector *v, int s)`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just a tip: Don't use pointers in C++. There's always a reasonably better alternative.

Comment: @David not always; a non-owning pointer is best expressed as a raw pointer (when you can't use a reference, such as member of a class that needs to be assignable (or the member itself needs to be assignable) or when it can be nullable).

Comment: Can pointers be avoided altogether in C++?

Comment: @rgamber depends on what you need to do. Mostly they can, especially if you're writing application code. But sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would `void vector_init(Vector v, int s)`, without the reference operator, be wrong?

If you don't pass `v` by reference, a copy of `v` will be made when enters function `vector_init` and you operate on that copy. After `vector_init` returns that temporary copy will be destroyed, so `vector_init` has no effect to your original `v`. To manipulate on original `v`, you need to pass `v` by reference(same to other type).

> Also are there any alternate ways to do this? like say `void vector_init(Vector *v, int s)`?

Pass by reference is better choice compare to pass by pointer.

Comment: Oh. So when I do Vector v, it is passing by the value of the reference and not the reference itself, and hence the &. Am I right?

Comment: `Vector v` is passing the value of `v`. `Vector& v`' is passing the reference of v.

Comment: Oh..I see, so the entire value of v as a struct will be passed. So the changes will take place on the copy and original v will remain unchanged.Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

There is no "reference operator".

The `&` declarator only gets added to the function parameter you want to be passed by reference. Passing a reference argument looks identical to passing by value.

Answer (score 1):

Actually passing a value **by reference** (`void vector_init(Vector &v, int s)`) or **by pointer** `void vector_init(Vector *v, int s)` have basically the same meaning.

The main difference is that when you pass by reference you are forced to pass a valid parameter (`NULL` wouldn't work) and that when you pass by pointer you must explicitly convert your argument to a pointer (while this is automatically done when passing by reference)

When you pass something **by value** as in void `vector_init(Vector v, int s)` it's different: the argument is copied through copy constructor and every modification made inside the scope of the function is local to the local copy of the argument, you cannot modify the original argument through a pass by value. You are not really passing your variable, you are passing a copy of it.

This even means that, if the argument is a large class or struct or has an expensive copy constructor, then also performance issues can occur.

Comment: The argument passed by value is not always copied, it can be moved as well.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: isn't it possible just with rvalue references?

Comment: No, rvalue references are just a reference, not a copy. Moving occurs when a value is initialised with an rvalue reference (and there is a move constructor). The compiler will convert an xvalue into an rvalue reference automatically when it can. Also another option that is even better, the copy/move can be elided (a compiler optimisation) and not even a move occurs.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I just found this useful link regarding the topic: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/, it seems quite interesting, thank you for pointing out this.